# How to use Babel without Webpack?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I compiled my simple code like below using babel.

```
var aa = new Promise();
```

to

```
"use strict";

require("core-js/modules/es.object.to-string");

require("core-js/modules/es.promise");

var aa = new Promise();
```

However, the old browser like IE9 could not execute that code. Because browser could not resolve the path **core-js/modules/es.object.to-string**.

Must I use webpack to using polyfill?

I don't want to use webpack.

My babel setting in package.json is below.

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "corejs": 3,
          "useBuiltIns": "usage",
          "targets": ">0.2%, not dead, not ie <= 11, not op_mini all"
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: No browser supports `require`. You need a module bundler to compile the files into a single one or include the files directly via `<script>`.

Comment: @FelixKling Is there a way to automatically add a script? like this `"use strict"; ....Code of core-js/modules/es.promise... var aa = new Promise();`

Answer (score 0):

You can include your polyfills scripts using a `<script>` tag in your index html file and properly ordering your polyfills and application scripts. `require` is not a recognized command by browsers. It is a server-side implementation from node.js.

You could probably consider using `import` instead?

`import 'core-js';`

or specific modules as shown here https://github.com/zloirock/core-js

`import 'core-js/features/promise';` -> Will modify global namespace

`import Promise from 'core-js-pure/features/promise';` -> Will not modify the global namespace

Comment: It work same when I use `import 'core-js/features/promise` on my top of the code. I want to load that code instead of require function.

Comment: `"use strict";

....Code of core-js/modules/es.promise...

var aa = new Promise();
`